# Why ignoring of Interface Segregation Priciple may become cause of connection beetwen client classes?

Tags: java, oop, solid-principles

I don't understand Interface Segregation Principle (ISP).

```
 public interface SenderAndSaver {

void send();
void save();

}



public class Sender1 implements SenderAndSaver{

@Override
public void send() {
    // do something
}

@Override
public void save() {
    // do something
}

}

public class Sender2 implements SenderAndSaver{

@Override
public void send() {
    // do something
}

@Override
public void save() {
    // do something
}

}

public class Saver1 implements SenderAndSaver{

@Override
public void send() {
    // do something
}

@Override
public void save() {
    // do something
}

}

public class Saver2 implements SenderAndSaver{

@Override
public void send() {
    // do something
}

@Override
public void save() {
    // do something
}

}
```

So, I have a "fat" interface. I have 4 classes that implements that interface. Next, the client classes use them as follows:

```
    public class SenderClient {


public void someMethod(SenderAndSaver sas){
    sas.send();
}
}

public class SaverClient {

public void someMethod(SenderAndSaver sas){
    sas.save();
}

}
```

One client need only method `send()`, other client need only method `save()`. I heard, that if method `send()` will be changed,  for example, add a parameter, it will affect the SaverClient. But why? The main idea is that `SaverClient` doesn't use method `send()`. Otherwise, the interface would't be fat, if all customers use all the methods. But if `SaverClient` does not use the method `send ()`, how changes in `send ()` can affect on `SaverClient`?

Comment: Why do the senders implement the save() method? Why do the savers implement the send() method? What do the clients (that don't implement anything) have to do with ISP?

Answer (score 1):

By having a single *fat* interface, you are trading off the simplicity of managing less interfaces, against the complexity of having code that is harder to reason about.

Take *SenderClient* as an example. Say, I wanted to change the code and also call the *save* method from somewhere within it. Even though I have "access" to the *save* method through the interface, I would need to go and check the code which provides the dependency to ensure that the instance which is provided, does actually support the *save* method, since it wasn't previously required (the object may not have an implementation for it).

Another way to think about it is this. *SenderClient* declares that it has a dependency which needs to be satisfied (provided). But, it is **not** fully dependent on that interface, and the only way to know what it REALLY is dependent on, is to look at the source code - but, that's exactly the problem you are trying to avoid by introducing an interface in the first place.

Your question specifically asked about *SaverClient* being affected by changes to the *send* method. Even though, like you point out, it will not require code changes to *SaverClient*, it is conceivable that in a large project, some of the "clients" may by in separate projects. A change to the signature of the *send* method (or anything in the *SenderAndSaver* interface) is likely to trigger recompilation of the project. This is again because you are inhibiting the compiler's ability to reason about the code.

I can think of yet another potential problem with your setup. What if, for example, you have a *SenderAndSaver* implementation which requires an *SmtpClient* for sending, and a *DbConnection* for saving. When constructing the implementation, both of these dependencies will need to also be constructed and provided to it. Yet, one of them will most likely not be used, since the client ultimately only depends on one of the two operations. This results in a waste of resources and is generally just a bad design.

This is a longer answer than I hoped to provide, but I think necessary in order to explain all the pertinent issues. Remember that design is all about trade-offs, and questions on principles are highly subjective. You need to look at the situation as a whole and in the context of your project and make the design decisions accordingly.